# Can someone explain from the return e.index part?

Tags: python, count, integer, list-comprehension, boolean-expression

```
def test(numbers):
    e = [int(i) % 2 == 0 for i in numbers.split()]
    return e.index(True) + 1 if e.count(True) == 1 else e.index(False) + 1
```

#the question was to identify the index position of the odd number
i understood the list comprehension part, but i am not getting the boolean part here. it would be a great help if somebody helps me get through this.

Can anybody help me from return ?

Answer (score 0):

`e` is a python `list`. The `e.index` and `e.count` methods are instance methods on the list. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists for more information.

> `list.index(x[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.
>
> The optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in the slice notation and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the start argument.
>
> `list.count(x)`
>
> Return the number of times x appears in the list.

So in your case, `e.count(True)` counts how many times `True` appears in the list. If there is only one `True` value, then the index of that value + 1 is returned. Otherwise, the index of the first `False` value + 1 is returned.